# nearby venue to iphone into simple array

Tags: iphone, google-maps, core-location, foursquare, nsmutabledictionary

Im really having a hard time figuring this out. Ive read a bunch of PDFS and stackoverflow questions on this but I have never used and API and can't quiet get it. 
I am trying to get my longitude and latitude coordinates and use any API out there (foursquare, google maps, any others you can recommend that are free?) to get a list of nearby parks and just put it into an NSMutableDictionary key=name object=@"distance". No need to get all its content, just distance and name. But I have been stuck on the first part, getting my longitude and latitude coordinates for over 4 hours. Can anyone show me code wise **`how I would get my coordinates`**, no need to explain how to parse the API, once i have my coordinates I feel like I can figure that out. Ive downloaded apples locateme source code but still cant get it to work on mine. Is there maybe a set of easy to follow steps or code someone can provide that I can just use and get this headache over with? Ive imported the location framework. Is there a quick 10-20 lines of code to solve this, not 3 additional view controllers with so much I dont quiet understand.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];    
}

#pragma mark Current location methods
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    latit = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    longit = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@"latitude = %f",latit);
    NSLog(@"longitude = %f",longit);

    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self getNearByList];
}

-(void)getNearByList
{    
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
    NSString *currentDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [dateFormat release];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=%f,%f&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE&v=%@&limit=100&radius=2000&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735,4bf58dd8d48988d176941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1ed941735,4bf58dd8d48988d119951735,4bf58dd8d48988d123941735,4d954afda243a5684865b473,4edd64a0c7ddd24ca188df1a,4bf58dd8d48988d1c9941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1bd941735,4bf58dd8d48988d124951735,4bf58dd8d48988d115951735,4bf58dd8d48988d11a951735,4bf58dd8d48988d10c951735,4bf58dd8d48988d11b951735,4bf58dd8d48988d11e951735,4bf58dd8d48988d1f9941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1f5941735,4bf58dd8d48988d113951735,4f04afc02fb6e1c99f3db0bc,4bf58dd8d48988d110951735,4bf58dd8d48988d1f2941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1fd941735,4bf58dd8d48988d103951735,4bf58dd8d48988d104941735,4f04aa0c2fb6e1c99f3db0b8,4d1cf8421a97d635ce361c31,4bf58dd8d48988d1f8941735,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4bf58dd8d48988d16d941735,4bf58dd8d48988d128941735,4bf58dd8d48988d111951735,4bf58dd8d48988d1ca941735,4bf58dd8d48988d117951735,4bf58dd8d48988d107951735,4bf58dd8d48988d1fa941735,4bf58dd8d48988d118951735,4bf58dd8d48988d17f941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1ac941735,4bf58dd8d48988d180941735",latit,longit,currentDate] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  //YOU CAN FOUND MORE CATEGORY ID AT FOURSQURE WEBSITE..
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval: 30.f];
    NSLog(@"url = %@",urlRequest);
    webData1 = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: urlRequest delegate: self];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
        [webData1 setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
        [webData1 appendData:data];
        //NSLog(@"webData1 = %@",webData1);
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message : @"An error has occured."
                                                        delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle :@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles :nil];
        [alert1 show];
        [alert1 release];

        [webData1 release];
    [connection release];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
        NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData1 mutableBytes] length:[webData1 length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"data = %@",data);

        [connection release];
        [webData1 release];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Place Api.You just need to register and than you will get key for api

//example api. This api will give you food in your defined radius of longitude and latitude in the json data format

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

[Google Place API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches)

Hope, this will help you..enjoy...